# CSS unable to get rid of UL's first and last child's dividers

Tags: css, html, css-selectors

I have a `nav` that holds a `ul` with several `il`s. The problem is that im unable to get rid of the `ul`'s `first` and `last child`'s divider.

here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Rvs3C/1/

i've added this code to my CSS file but seems like it makes no difference:

```
nav ul a li:first-child{
    content: none;
}

nav ul a li:last-child{
    content: none;
}
```

Comment: Your markup is wrong! `li`s can't be inside `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned elsewhere your HTML structure is off, `li` must me a direct child of `ul`, no other element as a child is valid. With this said, you also need to change your selectors per the below.

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/Rvs3C/6/)

HTML

```
<nav>
    <ul class="showing">
        <li><a href="#">home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">about me</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">content</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">browse</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">rate</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav_arr"><a href="#"><img src="http://www.irvinewelsh.net/images/arrow-left.png" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
nav {
    margin-right: 150px;
}
nav ul {
    background-color: #494A4C;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: right;
}
nav li img {
    margin-left: 20px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family:arial;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
nav ul li:first-child:before {
    content: none;
}
nav ul li:last-child:before {
    content: none;
}
nav li:before {
    content:"|";
    padding: 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:lightblue;
    font-size: 20px;
}
nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You markup is wrong. The corret way is `<a>` tag being the children of tag `<li>`.

The way you made ​​the correct selector would:

```
nav ul a:first-child li{
    content: none;
}

nav ul a:last-child li{
    content: none;
}
```

But remembering, this is not the right way to do.

The correct is change you html to:

```
 <ul class="showing">
       <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        ...
```